# При уменьшении размеров картинки нужна только центральная часть

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Всем привет. Есть картинка:

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url('http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg" alt="">
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении ее размеров к примеру 150 на 150 бралась за основу только ее центральная часть (с миньонами), а несущественная часть отбрасывалась  и желательно без использования скриптов.

[ссылка на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9dpsfjd/)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можете обрезать всё ненужное при помощи clip: rect()

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url('http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  clip: rect(10px,125px,140px,10px);
}
```

Comment: тоже классный подход! спасибо!

Comment: ну если [такая](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) картина вас устраивает, то можно и так

Comment: @vihtor, я не использовал clip-path (хотя можно, но поддержка...)
это свойство clip и оно поддерживается достаточно хорошо, можете посмотреть тут: http://htmlbook.ru/css/clip

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать div'ом

```
<style>
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg) 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover; /* можно убрать */
}
</style>

<div></div>
```

Но это не самое лучше решение, потому что картинки не должны размещаться на сайте в виде фона. Будет правильнее размещать их на сайте с помощью тега img

В этом случае можно пропробовать добавить тег картинки где-то рядом в скрытом виде

Comment: тогда уже `background: url('http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg') center no-repeat;` Все же надеюсь, может у кого появится решение поизящнее без правки html

Comment: сомневаюсь, в таких случаях обычно картинки нарезаются сервером, под нужные размеры. и запрашиваются так _/images/avatar/%ID%/100/120_. Просто если картинка будет большая, клиенту придется загружать её всю для того что бы потом сжать и увидеть её маленькую. Вот пример с гитхаба _https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/1996423?v=3&s=460_

Answer (score 0):

Задать через background-size: 100%, background-size:cover, и backgroud url("") 50% 50%;

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: .name{
background: url(http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg) 50% 50%;
background-size: 100%;
background-size: cover;
}


или вставить img, обрезать обверткой .img-wrapper через hide;
и выставить img размеры.

Comment: и все равно не ясно. я правильно записал?http://jsfiddle.net/h5qbofnu/