# На сайте wordpress не удается отобразить картинку также, как на html страничке

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, css3

В продолжении [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445218/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/445229#445229) - пытаюсь тупо перенести [картинку](http://jsfiddle.net/ck93gxq8/1/) (мне нужна оригинальная не растянутая центральная часть) на [сайт wordpress тестовый](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/22/)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -20%;
  margin-left: -280px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

но аналогичного эффекта получить не удается.. Добавил картинку и стили через инструменты разработчика, но она сжимается и растягивается..
[image: но она сжимается и растягивается..]
Буду благодарен за подсказки по помощь!

Comment: А разве у вас там прямо в коде html не прописаны высота и ширина для каждой картинки? Если да, то css не будет действовать.

Comment: @Visman я с html их удалил и прописал в css `width:100%; height:100%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в стилях прописано для всех тегов `img max-width: 100%;`. Уберите, потом должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что стиль img еще где-то перебивается. А если попробовать принудительно задать класс? Пример

```
<img  class='img-center' src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg" alt="">
```

Ну и класс соответственно

```
.img-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -20%;
  margin-left: -280px;
}
```

Comment: нет, такое не прокатывает